# Display jquery ui tooltip without hover event

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I'm looking at [JQuery UI Tooltip widget's documentation for show method.](http://api.jqueryui.com/tooltip/#option-show)  Trying to figure out how to show tooltip by calling show method.

Here is [JSFiddle code that I thought would work](http://jsfiddle.net/mAhBf/) but doesn't. I'm not sure why.

html

```
<input id="input_box" title='display this helpful stuff for user'/>
<button id="trigger">show tooltip</button>
```

javascript

```
$("#trigger").on('click', function(){
   $("#input_box").tooltip({ show: { duration: 800  } });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try something like this (trigger the `mouseenter` event of `textbox`)

```
$(function(){
    $(document).on('click', '.ui-tooltip-content', function(){
        $("#input_box").trigger('mouseleave');
        $("#input_box").tooltip('destroy');
    });

    $("#trigger").on('click', function(){
        $("#input_box").tooltip({ show: { duration: 800  } });
        $("#input_box").trigger('mouseenter');
    });
});
```

[**DEMO.**](http://jsfiddle.net/heera/mAhBf/3/)

But this is maybe not proper way to do this, instead, you can find `tooltip` plugins and those could be used by a click handler or you can create a simple one that could be designed using a click handler, but I don't recommend to use this kind of heck.